# mysqlcheck: unknown variable 'max_allowed_packet=100M'

Tags: mysql

I get the following error when I try to use `mysqlcheck`, `mysqlrepair` or `mysqlanalyze`:

```
mysqlcheck: unknown variable 'max_allowed_packet=100M'
```

I am trying to find whether there are any corrupt tables or indexes.

Background:

- MySQL  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.24, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
- I used the command `mysqlcheck  -u xxxx -h xxx.xxx.xx.xx -d xxxx -p xxxxx`

my.cnf

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
default-character-set = utf8
max_allowed_packet = 100M
```

Under [client]

Comment: [client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
default-character-set = utf8
max_allowed_packet = 100M

Under [cliebt]

Comment: Remove max_allowed_packet = 100M from [client] Section and then execute mysqlcheck.Please have a look at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68313) (resolved as "not a bug"), you shouldn't put settings for `mysqld` in the `[client]` section of your `.ini` file.

Put the `max_allowed_packet` option in the `[mysqld]` section instead.

See [Using Option Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html) for more details.

Comment: ...afaik it's a valid (and required for some purposes) setting for clients.  I've got a database with an unreasonably large blob in it which clients can't retrieve unless both the client and server have the option.  See it mentioned here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Answer (score 1):

Add `max_allowed_packet`, open

`my.ini/my.cnf` under `[mysqld]` section.

Once the change is done you would have to restart the server